# How Long Should I Wait After a "I’ll be in touch soon" reply, to follow Up?

Tags: united-states, postdocs, etiquette, email

After writing to a potential postdoc advisor in the US, I got replied like;

```
"... will follow up soon.    
....................
...new project is matching with your profile.
....................    
Again, I’ll be in touch soon. "
```

I genuinely like this research group's work. This is one of my best choices among those that I still have a chance for.

Just for the cultural differences and curiosity, I would like to know,

How to politely follow up?

Because waiting longer makes my other chances fade away. So I want to make sure if I am In or OUT.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the first two questions, since nobody except the potential advisor can answer these questions. I don't see a reason to doubt him being genuine, but again, only he knows.

Answer (score 1):

A reply is appropriate after a few days. Say you are (very) interested in the position and ask if there are other actions you should take at this time.

Asking for something specific is more likely to result in a follow up reply than just the "thanks".

If you have specific time constraints, not just worries, you should probably mention them. But academic time can have a very slow clock at times. This is one of those times.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems that you haven’t interviewed. He/she may be waiting for a deadline before starting interviews, or for a certain number of candidates. In my experience, this stage took for days to months. Asking after a few days about the next steps won’t hurt you.